# MIPS int read byte by byte to hex

Tags: mips

This is the prompt:
Part I
Write a MIPS assembly language program to
1. Prompt the user for an integer (that could be positive or negative)
2. Store that number in a memory location labeled MyNumber
3. Read that number byte-by-byte into register $t0 then print out that byte in hexadecimal, starting from lower address, with each byte is preceded with a string to indicate the byte position.
For example:
B0   0x 0A
B1   0x 12
B2   0x 65
B3   0xBE

I am at a loss of how to approach the conversion of an int into it's 4 bytes and then converting those to hex.

This is what I have so far:

```
.data
prompt:     .asciiz "Enter an integer (positive or negative): "
MyNumber:       .word 0
output:         .word 0
space:          .space 20

.text
main:
    addi $v0, $zero, 4  #code 4 is to print string
    la $a0, prompt      #loads string into register
    syscall

    addi $v0, $zero, 5  #code 5 is to read an integer
    syscall

    sw $v0, MyNumber        #stores value from $v0 to input

    la $t1, MyNumber
```

Comment: Did you try `lb` (load byte) with an offset and system call 34 (write in hexadecimal)?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should load consecutive bytes from the register using byte offsets. I have tried to solve the problem with MIPS code below. This program might not be perfect but I think that it makes the right i/o with MARS.

```
.data
prompt:     .asciiz "Enter an integer (positive or negative): "
s1:     .asciiz "B1: 
s2:     .asciiz " B2: 
s3:     .asciiz " B3: 
s4:     .asciiz " B4: 
MyNumber:       .word 0
output:         .word 0
space:          .space 20

.text
main:
    addi $v0, $zero, 4  #code 4 is to print string
    la $a0, prompt      #loads string into register
    syscall

    addi $v0, $zero, 5  #code 5 is to read an integer
    syscall

    sw $v0, MyNumber        #stores value from $v0 to input

    addi $v0, $zero, 4  #code 4 is to print string
    la $a0, s1      #loads string into register
    syscall

    la $t1, MyNumber
    lb $a0, 0($t1)
    lb $t0, MyNumber  
    addi $v0, $zero, 34
    syscall

    addi $v0, $zero, 4  #code 4 is to print string
    la $a0, s2      #loads string into register
    syscall

    lb $a0, 1($t1)  
    addi $v0, $zero, 34 #print in hexadecimal
    syscall

    addi $v0, $zero, 4  #code 4 is to print string
    la $a0, s3      #loads string into register
    syscall

    lb $a0, 2($t1) 
    addi $v0, $zero, 34
    syscall

    addi $v0, $zero, 4  #code 4 is to print string
    la $a0, s4      #loads string into register
    syscall


    lb $a0, 3($t1) 
    addi $v0, $zero, 34
    syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your code that converts to hexadecimal also it may be a good idea to pass the integer on to one of the $t registers.

Also when it is converted maybe using lw instead of la is a better move. If I were you I would convert the number to hexadecimal mathematically then print the output i.e. divide by 16 etc.

So essentially you would be using the same register e.g. $t3 to do the mathematical operations. then you can use sw to save the hexadecimal. Then you can print it to the screen.

I would advise creating a function which is called in main by either j or jal for the hexadecimal calculation.